# Prove that $A_3(4,3)=9$ and construct the correspoding code.

Tags: coding-theory

- $A_q(n,d)$ is the maximum $M$ (number of codewords) such that a $q$-ary $(n, M, d)$-code exists.

I know that according to Gilbert-Varshamov bound:

$$A_q(n,d) \left( \binom {n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} (q-1)+ \dotsb +\binom{n}{e}(q-1)^e\right) \leq q^n. $$

In our case we solve that for $n=4$, $d=3$ and $e=1$ (the errors that it can correct) and we have that $A_3(4,3)$ $\leq 9$.
I assume that the code $C$ contains the $0000$. Since $d = 3$ (minimum distance) so every codeword would have weight $\geq 3$.

How many codewords with weight $=3$ and weight$=4$ should be in the code? And which are these?(*NOTE: we have $q=3$*)

How can I prove that $A_3(4,3)=9$ ? Is there a standard way to construct such codes?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: [The Gilbert-Varshamov bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound) is a **lower bound** to $A_q(n,d)$. You seem to be talking about [The Hamming bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound). The Hamming bound is an upper bound. And there are no guarantees that it can be achieved. Therefore there obviously is no general method of construction either.

Comment: But, for these parameters there happen to exist codes achieving the Hamming bound. You can construct them as 2-dimensional linear codes easily enough. Or use a check matrix. A ternary $2\times4$ matrix with pairwise linearly independent columns is all you need. The code I just jotted down has no words of weight four.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it! So,I followed your method with the check matrix and I found a code with 9 codewords:{$0000,1012,0122,2021,0211,1101,2110,1220,2202$} .I see that every distance between the codewords is equal to $3$ and there are no words of weight four.

Comment: Good job! Why don't you post it as answer!

Comment: I posted one more way to solve this problem.Although the lemma is a bit specified for $d=3$,it's very useful.Check it if you don't mind.And thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hamming bound I found that $A_3(4,3)\leq9$. I have $n=4$ and $q=3$. I want to find a code with $3^2$ codewords. So $k=2$.
I know that the check matrix is an $(n-k)\times n$ matrix. Also,I know that $d=3$ so I want to construct a check matrix $H\in M_{2\times 4}(\Bbb F_3)$ where there aren't two columns linearly dependent (that means the columns are pairwise linearly independent). I have:

$$H= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
(Check: $column3 + column4 = column2$)

And the generator matrix G  would be:

$$G=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

So, now it's easy to find the code.

$$C=\{0000,1012,0122,2021,0211,1101,2110,1220,2202\} \subset \Bbb F_3^4.$$

We notice that every distance between the codewords is equal to $3$ and that there are no words of weight $4$.

So, we have proved that $A_3(4,3)=9$.

Comment: To get minimum distance three what you need is that no two columns of $H$ are linearly dependent. That is exactly the property your $H$ has. None of the columns $(2,1)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ is a scalar multiple of another, and this forbids codewords of weight two. The column space is two-dimensional, so any three vectors will automatically be dependent no matter what.

Comment: Oh yes! You are right!! Thanks again! I will correct it.

Answer (score 2):

***Another way to solve this*** (But without the construction of the code)

By using the following lemma:

**Lemma**:If q is a prime power and $n=\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}$ for some $r\geq2$, then $A_q(n,3)= q^{n-r}$ .

In our case, we have $n=4$ and $q=3$ so we search an r such that $n=\frac{3^r-1}{3-1}=4$.It is obvious that $r=2$ satisfies the equation. So, $A_3(4,3)= 3^{4-2}=9$ .